# How to change models name in django from django admin interface?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

using "verbose_name" we can change the models name, but here i want this process to be kind of dynamic, like from inside admin panel itself, it will be renamed, so that it will not have to be hard coded.

can anybody suggest any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement some sort of model for this that will store the changed model names, like:

```
class ModelName(models.Model):
    model_key = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    model_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

def model_name(name):
    try:
        return ModelName.objects.get(model_key=name).model_name
    except ModelName.DoesNotExist:
        return name
```

Next we can make a class that lazily resolves the name, like:

```
from django.utils.functional import lazy

model_name_lazy = lazy(model_name, str)
```

Now we can set the name of an object to:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):

    # ...

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = model_name_lazy('mymodel')
```

By then modifying the `ModelName` model, for example on the Django admin pages, you can add/change a `ModelName` object with `model_key` is `'mymodel'`, and then the verbose name of that model will be the corresponding `model_name` field.